# Firebase analytics screen view events not visible on crashlytics when proguard on

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, firebase-analytics

Im using Firebase analytics and Firebase Crashlytics in my android app.

With my debug build, im able to see `screen_view` analytics events in Crashlytics crash details Logs tab. This works as expected on my debug build, with out Proguard.

When I enable proguard, I no longer see `screen_view` events in my Crashlytics crash details Logs tab. I can see the `screen_view` events in Firebase analytics reports and in debug view, but they are not linked to my Crashlytics crashes.

Should I use some custom Proguard rules?

**Update:**

Im using following lib versions:

- `com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1`
- `io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4`
- `com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1`
- `com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.4`

Comment: Are you using the firebase plugin in Android Studio?

Comment: I have done the integration like explained in this "Manually add Firebase" chapter https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Comment: Try using the firebase plugin https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#use_the_firebase_assistant It can deobfuscate your code because it will pull in the proguard mappings when you compile a new build

Comment: I tried to add Firebase with Android Studio plugin, but the result is the same. I can not see `screen_view` events in crashes but the `screen_view` events are visible in analytics so the analytics plugin is able to pick the screen (activity) names etc.

Comment: Same for me, the analytics events don't appear in the release version of my app in Crashlytics.

Comment: Does anybody have any idea? :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you try including this in your proguard config file?

```
-keep class com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement$OnEventListener { *; }
```

I had a similar issue and it worked for me.

Comment: Thanks, that indeed fixes the issue!

Comment: I added these lines to my proguard but I still cannot see the screen_view log event with the crash. Do you have another solution?

Comment: Hey Andy P, that's weird. what the versions of your SDKs?

Comment: I also noticed that my recent crashreports does not contain any more `screen_view` events. :(

Comment: @dev.for.fun does this still work for you? It stopped showing the screen_view events for me a long time ago as well

Comment: yes it does. it stopped working for me some time ago but I noticed that I need to update my SDK versions.